# pgbouncer postgres multiple django sites

Tags: django, postgresql, pgbouncer

I am trying to learn a bit of pgbouncer with postgres and django - but I seem to have a problem when under production.

So, I have a django site say `site1`, which uses the following django database `settings.py`:

```
SECRET_KEY = "dbpassword"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'site1db1',                      
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': SECRET_KEY,
        'HOST': 'localhost',                     
        'PORT': '12517', # custom pgbouncer post                     
      }
   }
```

the above works all fine with `site1` - and this is running live on production. Now, I introduce another django site (separate django installation) called `site2` with a new database `site2db2`. So, at the moment, I have my settings.py for `site2` in django as follows:

```
SECRET_KEY = "dbpassword"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
        'NAME': 'site2db2',                      
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': SECRET_KEY,
        'HOST': 'localhost',                     
        'PORT': '12517', # custom pgbouncer post                     
      }
   }
```

unfortunately, when I try to `syncdb` this second django site, I get;

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ERROR:  Auth failed
```

I am assuming that this is because `site1` is using the same port as `site2`? How does one get around this problem. Any guidance pointing me to the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your django application's connection string is still using postgresql username and password. Set the connection string to the port number, username, and password of pgbouncer. Check auth_type in the config file of pbBouncer, set it to trust and see if it works.

Hope that this gives you a hint

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by `May be your django application's connection string is still using postgresql username and password.`? I am using the same username, password for both the django  sites - It is just the database name which is different - is this not how it is supposed to be? Sorry if the question is 101.

Comment: I have never used django but I think that instead of USERNAME postgres and PASSWORD SECRET_KEY, you should use the pgbouncer username.and password. This is found in the pgbouncer config file, auth_type field.